# What is Pointer authentication code in Xcode 10.1?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode10.1

In release note of Xcode 10.1, I came to know that new architecture introduced named `arm64e` and this architecture improves and introduced many compiler level features. One of them is `Pointer authentication code(PAC)`.

What changes to consider when we run existing developed application using Xcode 10.1 to leverage PAC? and What are the benefits of it ?